# How do i use interval 1 hour in group by in Clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I need a clickhouse query to group by hour interval for the given date `>= today()-7`.

I have tried `date + INTERVAL 1 HOUR` but it is not working in the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works when grouping expression *date + INTERVAL 1 HOUR* is not defined in *select*-clause:

```sql
SELECT count()
FROM 
(
    SELECT arrayJoin([toDate('2021-06-01'), toDate('2021-06-02')]) AS date
    WHERE date >= (today() - 2)
)
GROUP BY date + toIntervalHour(1)

/*
┌─count()─┐
│       1 │
│       1 │
└─────────┘
*/
```

If you need this value in *select*-clause use this query:

```sql
SELECT
    date + toIntervalHour(1) AS date1,
    count()
FROM 
(
    SELECT arrayJoin([toDate('2021-06-01'), toDate('2021-06-02')]) AS date
    WHERE date >= (today() - 2)

)
GROUP BY date1

/*
┌───────────────date1─┬─count()─┐
│ 2021-06-02 01:00:00 │       1 │
│ 2021-06-01 01:00:00 │       1 │
└─────────────────────┴─────────┘
*/
```

Comment: it didnt work, it gives me the count for the whole day still when i tried both possibilities. i need the count each hour for a day. i tried the below too but not working. SELECT date + toIntervalHour(1) AS date1, count(date1) from noc.interface where date>=(today()-2) group by date1

Comment: try this query: *SELECT date + toIntervalHour(1) AS date1, count(date1) from (select * from noc.interface where date>=(today()-2)) group by date1*.